# How to get json values using jackson parser in android

Tags: android, jackson

i want to get json values using jackson parser.
my json format is

```
{
"msg" : "success",
"response" : "1",
"Empinfo": {
"name" : "ram",
"age" : "20"
}
}
```

i want to acces EmpInfo so i created class like this

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class LoginResponse extends BaseResponse implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonProperty("Empinfo")
    private EmployeeInformation employeeInfo;

    public EmployeeInformation get_user_details() {
        return employeeInfo;
    }

    public void EmployeeInformation(EmployeeInformation employeeInfo) {
        this.employeeInfo = employeeInfo;
    }

    public static class EmployeeInformation {
        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String name;

        @JsonProperty("age")
        private String age;

       public String getname() {
           return name;
       }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getage() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setage(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    }

}
```

How to access that object from my login activity onResponseListener

```
@Override
public void onResponseReceived(Object response, int requestType) {
    switch(requestType) {
        case Constants.LOGINID:
        if(response instanceof LoginResponse) {
            LoginResponse loginRes = (LoginResponse)response;
            if(loginRes.getResponse() == 1)
            {
               //here i want access that information
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "fails", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to acces that object and get that information getname() and getage().

sorry for poor english. thanks.

Comment: Hey suresh may be your json is not correct see here http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onResponseReceived(Object response, int requestType) {
    switch(requestType) {
        case Constants.LOGINID:
        if(response instanceof LoginResponse) {
            LoginResponse loginRes = (LoginResponse)response;
            if(loginRes.getResponse() == 1)
            {
               //here i want access that information
               loginRes.get_user_details().getname();// Access name.
               loginRes.get_user_details().getage();// Access age.
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "fails", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i put my json wrongly that is Empinfo only i updated my question

Comment: thks it's works. Please explain how that working i did not set name any where how getname working...?

Comment: The name is set when 'LoginResponse' object is instantiated (deserialized) by the Jackson JSON parser using the data provided in the JSON file. Requesting you to follow these naming conventions in future: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html